UITextView text (fragment) before newline disappears when animating
I'm using custom animation speed for contentOffset of a UITextView. It seems that UITextView is creating a new view (private _UITextLayoutFragmentView) for every 'newline' text, and when doing UIView animation block, they just disappears.
private func animate(offset: CGFloat, duration: TimeInterval) {

    let scrollEndPosition = textView.contentSize.height - textView.frame.height
    
    UIView.animate(
        withDuration: duration,
        delay: 0,
        options: .curveLinear) {
            self.textView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: scrollEndPosition)
        } completion: { _ in }
}


Using setContentOffset(_:animated:) works (but cannot use custom speed).
Newlines in UITextView are creating these _UITextLayoutFragmentView views:

The hierarchy is UITextView > _UITextContainerView > _UITextLayoutCanvasView > [_UITextLayoutFragmentView]
Any way to either prevent UITextView from splitting text to fragments or to animate it a different way?
